# Using a method on an object of an arraylist in Java

Tags: java, class, arraylist, methods

```
public class Book
{
private String isbn, author, area;
private int length;
public Book(String isbn, String author, String area, int length)
{
    this.isbn=isbn;
    this.author=author;
    this.area=area;
    this.length=length;
}
public boolean isLong()
{
    if (length>500)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}    
} 
public class BookCollection

{
 private ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();


public BookCollection()throws IOException
{
    Scanner fileScan;
    String oneLine;
    String isbn, author, area;
    int length;

    fileScan = new Scanner (new File("books.txt"));
    while (fileScan.hasNext())
    {
        isbn=fileScan.next();
        author=fileScan.next();
        area=fileScan.next();
        length=fileScan.nextInt();
        bookList.add(new Book(isbn, author, area, length));
    }
}
 public class TestBookCollection
{

public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException
{
    BookCollection books = new BookCollection();
    System.out.println(books);


}
}
```

All right here is the relevant code. My project is to read a text file that has the information about these books and put them into an arraylist of book objects. My question is: how would I go about envoking the isLong() method found in class Book on an object in an arraylist? The point of the method is, if an object has >500 pages that it returns true. If not it will return false. I'm just kind of confused about the logic and I have never really worked with Arraylists before.

Comment: thelist.get(theindex).isLong()

Answer (score 1):

You can add another method to BookCollection:

```
public void printLongBooks() {
  for (Book book : bookList) {
    if (book.isLong()) {
       well, book is long ...
    } else {
       obviously, it is short ...
 }
```

The above uses the so called "for each" looping style in Java that you can use to loop every array/collection; instead of the "old school" `for (int i=0; i<...)` counting loop.

and within your main method, you simply invoke the new method:

```
books.printLongBooks()
```

And some generic hints:

A) isLong() can be reduced to a one-liner: `return length > 500;`

B) **reading** stuff from a file is not what you directly do in the constructor. Instead, you should create a dedicated method to that, which you then might call within the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Rather than putting the logic to create book list inside a constructor, you should create a method named as getBookCollection() that returns an arraylist.

```
public List<Book> BookCollection()throws IOException
    {

        List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
        //logic to create booklist

        return booklist;
    }
```

Once you have list of books, you can run an enhanced for loop and check for pages in each book.

```
for(Book book: bookList){
        if(book.isLong()){
            //logic
        } else {
            //logic
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate through the elements of the `ArrayList` and call the method on each one of its objects.

```
for(Book book : bookList){
    boolean isLong = book.isLong();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `List<Book>`, where each index in the `List` contains a `Book`. Use the `List.get(index)` method to get the `Object` in the given `List` at index. For example: `bookList.get(0)` gets the `Book` at index 0. Once you have that `Object`, you can use it normally.

I assume that you have some way to get the `bookList` inside `BookCollection`, and the name of a `Book`?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    BookCollection books = new BookCollection(); // Make a new BookCollection
    List<Book> booksInCollection = books.getBooksList(); // Get the Books inside BookCollection
    // Go through each book in booksInCollection
    for(int index = 0; index < booksInCollection.size(); index++){
        // Get the Book Object at index
        Book currentBook = booksInCollection.get(index);
        if(currentBook.isLong()){
            System.out.println(currentBook.getName() + " is long!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly (if you don't want to use streams etc.) you need to get object from ArrayList. You can do it by using `ArrayList.get(int index)` and then invoking the method or by using for each loop:

```
for(Book book : bookList) {
    System.out.println(book.isLong());
}
```

The problem is that you cannot access private field (bookList) from main. There are several ways to make it work.

- Create a public method inside BookCollection
- Change field to public and then access it directly `books.bookList`
- Make a getter to your bookList in BookCollection
- Make BookCollection extends ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

What you've done here is created a *decorator* (`BookCollection`) which wraps an `ArrayList` with additional functionality (in this case, a constructor which pre-fills it based on a file). This gives you two options for how to make use of a `Book` in the `List`:

1. Make the `List` accessible via a getter, and then work it out. Makes statements long but this is acceptable for small amounts of usage:

   ```
   if(books.getBooks().get(index).isLong()) {
       //The book at index is long
   }
   ```
2. More commonly, you'll make methods in the decorator which offer common functionality, like so:

   ```
   public boolean isLong(int index) {
       return bookList.get(index).isLong();
   }
   ```

   Then you just call the decorator method from your business logic. You can even make more complex methods such as the one offered by GhostCat.